# How to know the completion of the three methods invoked by process.start() in .net(c#)

Tags: c#, .net, process, console-application

I have two exe(two console apps) named `first.exe` and `second.exe`, in which `first` is invoking `second` exe three times by using `Process.start()` and passing different arguments.After these three execution finishes i want to run a method(only after finishing three methods).How to do that.
This is the way i am handling the three invokes in `second.exe`

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            if (args[0] == "TC" && args[1] == "CS")
            {
                Processfiles("TCS");
            }
            if (args[0] == "RC" && args[1] == "CS")
            {
                Zipfiles("RCS");
            }
            if (args[0] == "CC" && args[1] == "CS")
            {
                Leveragefiles("CTS");
            }

            Downloadfiles();
}
```

Here my question is how to execute `Downloadfiles();` method after the completion of three methods `Processfiles("TCS");,Zipfiles("RCS");,Leveragefiles("CTS");`. Here the completion time of three methods vary at different times

Code used to start `second.exe` is

```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathExe"];
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dtr in ds.Tables["testG"].Rows)
                {
                    startInfo.Arguments = dtr["TC_CODE"].ToString() + " " + dtr["CC_CODE"].ToString();
                    Process.Start(startInfo);
                    // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathExe"], dtr["VENDOR_CODE"].ToString() + " " + dtr["TECH_CODE"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mail.SendMail2(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"], System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailCc"], null, ex.Message, "error", true);
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to start `second.exe`?

Comment: @BJ Myers ,i have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

you can use threading task for this.
Use the conditional operator on the task as it is

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Processfiles("TCS"));
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Zipfiles("RCS"));
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Leveragefiles("CTS"));
Task.WaitAll();//to make sure all the task is complete
 Downloadfiles();
```

Comment: But the invoke is from process.start(),you meant inside if loop?

Comment: Yes,just use the diagnostics while using it to make sure.